systemd: usage of AllowedCPUs vs. CPUAffinity
In Linux systemd, two different properties seem to address the same concern: AllowedCPUs and CPUAffinity. Both seem to restrain a running process to some defined CPUs (you can for instance restrict a process to the first three cores with a 0-2 value). I don't understand the difference and when to use one over the other.
Moreover, AllowedCPUs seems to be bases on cgroups, CPUAffinity on something called NUMA (Non-Uniform Memory Access). Here again, I don't get the point. I suspect that in some cases that I haven't identified, some systemd launched services are concerned with some cgroups management and in other case, there's not. Not very clear for me as you can see…
The documentation for each of those concept is quite clear, but I don't grasp the big picture.

Not all CPU (cores) are the same (and same capabilities, e.g. floating point, crypto functions)), and some CPU may be "farther away", so sharing less or no cache (L1 and maybe also L2).

OK, I already get this information and both properties give the ability to address specific cores according to the need of the process. But, it doesn't answer my question and the subtle differences between the two approaches.

I'm not sure what the question is however. Some people may have a use case for managing this on a cgroup level, some may have a use case for managing this on a process level, and both options were added by people who were willing to do the work to add them. So both options exist. You use whichever one suits your use case best or make a case and do the work for adding a third way for your use case (which may or may not be acceptable to the kernel devs).

The question is indeed to know when one is preferable to the other and how the two are interacting if both defined.
